# Equivalente masculino de «misógino»

Tags: significado, palavra-para-ideia, antónimos

Que palavra se usa para alguém que tem/sofre uma aversão aos homens? Se fosse às mulheres, adjectivaríamos essa pessoa de *misógina*.

Qualquer ajuda seria apreciada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A palavra é [***misândrico***](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mis%C3%A2ndrico), aquele que sofre de [***misandria*** (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/misandria). O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) define:

> **misandria** *s.f.* aversão, ódio ou desprezo pelos indivíduos do sexo masculino → p[or] opos[ição] a *misoginia*
>
> **misândrico** *adj.* **1** relativo a misandria **2** que apresenta misandria (diz-se de indivíduo)

Com significado algo próximo tens também [*andrófobo* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/andr%C3%B3fobo); o equivalente para mulheres é *ginecófobo* (vem no Houaiss; o Priberam tem apenas [*ginecofobia*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ginecofobia)). Mas aqui a tónica é na repugnância e medo, não no ódio ou desprezo.